# Set Style Class for all Aspx Components at Once

Tags: css

We have an aspx page with Twenty text boxes and couple of Dropdownlists.

Is it possible to set a style for all at once?

Comment: @.@ set all textboxes, dropdownlists with one `class`

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="id1" runat="server" CssClass="your-class-name">` and in your `css file` or in `<style></style>` part you can define that class like: `.your-class-name {color: #fff; font-size: 11px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be done simply with

```
 input, select {
    ... /* your common style here */
 }
```

but be careful since `select` elements are not completely customizable (depending on browser/OS) so some properties won't be applied in a crossbrowser way (e.g. you won't be able to change a border on a select using IE6)

You can also style some specific input element using an attribute selector, e.g.

```
 input[type="text"], select {
     ... /* this is applied only to input text and select
 }
```

attribute selector works an all modern browser, even on IE7

Comment: Can I exclude some components from this, example I dont want that css to be effected for my RadioButtons,Image Buttons and Comboboxes